# What is the use of final, while declaring the String variable?

Tags: java, class, static

My compiler was showing an error while declaring the String variable but the hints showed that final is missing. After correcting, it worked but what is the use of *final*?

```
class Outerclass
{
    private static String upa = "tobby";

    static class A
    {
        void printmessage(){
            System.out.println("who is a good boy?"+upa);                
        }           
    }
    class B
    {
        void printagain()
        {
            System.out.println("who is a bad boy?"+upa);
        }                    
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outerclass.A oa=new Outerclass.A();
        oa.printmessage();

        Outerclass outer= new Outerclass();
        outerclass.B ob= outer.new B();
        ob.printagain();         
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see final anywhere?

Comment: `final` means that the variable is guaranteed to be visible after class initialization, and that you can't accidentally (or deliberately) reassign it. It is not required (you won't get an error without it), but it is a good practice to make things which you treat like constants *actually constant*.

Comment: Apart from the fact that it's `String` and not `string`, your code runs fine and has no `final`.

Comment: There should be no problem in this code unless you are accessing that String while creating an anonymous class inside. Also String not string.

Comment: Please stick to naming conventions (class names starts uppercase) (outerclass, a, b), because it makes the reading of code more easy, if assumptions are met. I hope you meant String, not string - else you have to correct that line.

Answer (score 0):

`final` can be used on classes, methods and variables. If used on a class, it means that you cannot subclass it. For example, `String` is a final class, which means that you cannot extend it with your own class.

When used on a method, it means that the method cannot be overridden in a subclass. This can be useful, if you want to be sure that nobody using your code will change the implementation of your method.

On a variable, it's a bit more complicated. When you make a variable final, it means that you either have to give it a value during decleration:

```
final String dogSound = "woof";
```

or in a constructor:

```
final String dogSound;

public MyClass() {
    dogSound = "woof";
}
```

After this, you cannot assign a new value, not even in the constructor. The compiler will not let you.

However, it does **not** mean that a final object cannot have its contents altered. Given this array:

```
final String[] dogSounds = new String[1];
dogSounds[0] = "woof";
dogSounds[0] = "bark";
```

is perfectly legal.

So it's different from the so-called const-correctness there is in C and C++, where a `const` object actually has a different type.

Comment: You don't have to set it in a constructor. You can set it in an initializer.

Comment: That's what I wrote.

Comment: You wrote "When you make a variable final, it means that you either have to give it a value during decleration ... or in a constructor". You can also do it in an initializer: `final String dogSound; { dogSound = "woof"; }`.